# Browser cache not cleared when logging in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am making simple wordpress sites, but recently I turned on the "Allow new members to register" option. I did some tests and: when I'm logged out I visit some pages of my site, after that I log in and I'm redirected to the home page and it is correctly indicated that I am logged in. But then I visit the same pages, which I visited when I was logged out, and on them I appear as logged out. If I do a F5 refresh, I appear logged in again. To put it simply: my browser cache for the whole site does not get cleared when I log in. Is this normal behaviour and if no how can I fix it?

Comment: it's not normal. what cache plugin do you have in your website?

Comment: I don't have any cache plugins. I only have woocommerce, contact form 7 and a woocommerce wishlist.

Comment: any rules added into `.htaccess` files? or some settigns with cache turned on from hosting?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jjqw4e
upon inspection of the host I found this. It doesn't seem to have any settings though.